# Return an image from webservice

Tags: java, image, web-services

I want to make request to a web service which will return an image based on request parameter?
What is the best possible approach for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply make a Servlet serving image, pass the parameter to it process image based on param and return as a response, This would serve as a rest web service, You could also go for some standard implementation of webservice to achieve this

---

**Also Check**

- [BalusC's implementation of image servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Comment: I think *Filter* is the *best* way.

Comment: Filter mainly serves to filter requests, to serve request servlet is better option

Comment: A Filter is intended to modify a request; like wrapping it or adding parameters, or doing security checks.  Although you could hijack the request and server an image from there, that's not the intention of the tool.  For clarity, it makes a lot more sense to use a Servlet here.

Answer (score 1):

By web service you mean something in the web, or a Web Service using SOAP over HTTP?

If it's the first thing I should write a Servlet that depending on request parameters write the bytes of the image to the output stream (setting appropiate headers like Content-Type).

```
doGet(...) {
   request.setContentHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
   // write image bytes to request.getOutputStream()
   ...
}
```

If it's the second thing simply return a byte[] with the content. Or... if you need also the content-type, return a structure with `content-type: string` and `data: byte[]`.